# How do the Ranger features Hunter's Quarry and Prime Shot work?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, ranger

First of all. I'm really sorry if the question is so "dumb". There is nobody that can teach me at this point, and I'm really clueless

So I'm playing in this  [solo D&D](http://dnd.chromesphere.com/Solo_Adventures/The_Crypt_4e/Room2a.html)  And I currently in a room, here's a diagram.

http://dnd.chromesphere.com/Solo_Adventures/The_Crypt/Rooms/Room2a.png

s2 is where I am. a and b are dire rat.

I decided to attack this dire rat using my arrow (shortbow) to be precise (My Class is ranger. I'm a human. Level 1)

But how I resolved this?

And here's 2 points that I'd like to point out.

I'm a ranger. I have this class featured call "Hunter's Quarry"

> Once per turn as a minor action, you can designate the enemy nearest to you as your quarry.
>   Once per round, you deal extra damage to your quarry.
>   The extra damage is based on your level.
>   If you can make multiple attacks in a round, you decide
>   which attack to apply the extra damage to after all the attacks are rolled.
>   The hunter’s quarry effect remains active until the end of the encounter, until the
>   quarry is defeated, or until you designate a different target as your quarry.
>   You can designate one enemy as your quarry at a time.

Do I deal this damage even though I missed?

Then there is a class feature called "Prime Shot"

> If none of your allies are nearer to your target than you are, you receive a +1 bonus to ranged attack rolls against that target.

I'm lonely and I'm using arrows, how this affect the combat?

PS: It will be helpful and lovely if you don't just explain this one not just attacking but from deciding surprise round until the combat ends.

Thank You

Comment: While the question is not that dumb, it is really broad. I suggest you to split it in at least two questions. One is "what's the flow of combat" and the other one is "how do ranger abilities interact?" (I guess this could be further split into questions - I'll detail you after my D&D game ends)

Comment: @Zachiel I think that this can remain 1 question, both are questions about how Ranger Class mechanics trigger in play and the scenario he gives above is a good example for both.

Answer (score 4):

**When you put your Hunter's Quarry on a creature, the extra damage can only be added on a hit.**

Your rules quote was either out of date (missing errata) or just simply not a complete copy. Hunter's Quarry actually reads:

> **Hunter's Quarry**
>
> **At-Will
>   Minor Action**
>
> **Effect:** You can designate the nearest enemy to you that you can see as your quarry.
>   Once per round, ***when you hit your quarry with an attack***, the attack deals extra damage based on your level. If you can make multiple attacks in a round, you decide which attack to apply the extra damage to after all the attacks are rolled. If you have dealt Hunter’s Quarry damage since the start of your turn, you cannot deal it again until the start of your next turn.
>
> The hunter’s quarry effect remains active until the end of the encounter, until the quarry is defeated, or until you designate a different target as your quarry.
>
> You can designate one enemy as your quarry at a time.

I've italicized and bolded the pertinent rules.

**Prime Shot triggers when you are the closest PC to an enemy and you attack that enemy.**

In your case, Prime Shot would basically trigger on every attack you make because you would be closer than any other PC in the party (since there are not other PCs in the party).

Answer (score 2):

### Deciding Surprise Round

Usually, unless someone is hiding there's no surprise round. You enter the room and you see the rats the same moment the rats see you.
If you had some means to effectively sneak into the room without being seen (which involves getting superior concealment or using specific powers) and you managed to hide, the rats wouldn't expect an attack and you would have a surprise round on them.

### Combat begins!

Let's suppose you won initiative and the rats are still in their initial positions. If not, they're probably swarming you and as a ranged character you're either shifting away before attacking, using melee or close attacks or just giving them attacks of opportunities by shooting in melee.

So, since you won initiative it's your turn to act. You decide you want to mark an opponent because you have your bow readied already (you're exploring some dangerous place, aren't you?). You use your minor action and choose the nearest enemy.

The [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw6iy.png) shows you how distance is calculated.

If you were just one square higher the two rats would be the same distance from you (shocking, right?), and you can effectively move before using your minor if for some reason marking the "faraway" rat is what you need to do.

Then you shot, using your standard action, possibly using some power.
As Joshua said in his answer, since you're playing a solo adventure there are no other allies so Prime Shot always triggers (there are no other allies that can be nearer to the targets than you).
As Joshua also said, Hunter's Quarry's wording tells you to deal the extra damage on a hit. After each hit, you decide if applying the extra damage or not (I see no reason for not using it the first time you hit).